# Programmatically working with Outlook's OFT format (on linux)

Tags: outlook, oft

We have a project that has numerous Outlook OFT files. Users download these files and use them to send prewritten emails in Outlook.

I have been looking for a way to convert these files into plain text. Ideally, this conversion functionality would be incorporated into the web app that runs on Linux servers. I mention Linux because Outlook and OFT are Microsoft products.

I have not found any libraries, class, tutorials around this topic. I have found very little conversation besides trying to do HTML->OFT which points to a Microsoft only library. I am most experienced with PHP, but I am open to any approach.

FWIW, I believe OFT can have templating information in it. I am only interested in extracting the message content/body.

Answer (score 0):

OFT is the same an MSG (with a different class signature GUID). Whatever library you can find for working with MSG files, will work with OFT as well.